# How to return specific field queryset DRF

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I want to create a custom queryset class that returns different fields to pre-define two cases.

1. when `DateField` is greater than today
2. when it's less than today.

In case it's greater return all fields, else return only `date_to_open` and `post_name` fields.

`views.py`

```
class GroupDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def greater(self):
        return models.Group.objects.filter(shared_to=self.request.user, 
           date_to_open__gt=timezone.now()).exists()

 

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.greater():
            query_set = models.Group.objects.filter(shared_to=self.request.user, 
               date_to_open__gt=timezone.now())
        else:
            query_set = SPECIFIC FIELDS
        return query_set
```

`serializers.py`

```
class GroupDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.name')
    images = GroupImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    shared_to = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.UserProfile.objects.all(), 
       slug_field='name', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = ('id', 'group_name', 'owner', 'group_text', 'created_on', 'date_to_open', 'shared_to', 
    'images', )
```

Comment: override the `get_serializer_class()` class and check the `greater()` in it, rather than in `get_queryset()`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu could you please show how I can do that in Answer? I'll upvote as well:)

Comment: Are you trying to change the fields returned on a per-instance-basis, depending on the value for `date_to_open`? If so, that's not possible. Changing your serializer or changing `get_queryset` will effect all the objects returned by this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to @ArakkalAbu comment I've just overridden `get_serializer_class()`

views.py

```
class GroupDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def greater(self):
        return models.Group.objects.filter(shared_to=self.request.user, date_to_open__gt=timezone.now()).exists()


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.greater():
            return serializers.GroupDetailsSerializer
        else:
            return serializers.ClosedGroupDetailsSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using the same logic and use `values_list` to return specific values out of the Query set. The returned values is also a query set

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.greater():
        return models.Group.objects.filter(shared_to=self.request.user, date_to_open__gt=timezone.now())
    else:
        return models.Group.objects.filter(shared_to=self.request.user, date_to_open__lt=timezone.now()).values_list('date_to_open', 'post_name' , flat = True)
```